# Displaying Only Available Variables But Not With IF, Is It Possible?

Tags: php

Let's say I have this 'profile page' code :

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>First Name : </td>
<td>John</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name : </td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hobby : </td>
<td>Soccer</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

and those profile are stored from database and some fields are optional. For example : hobby, yahoo messenger ID, twitter ID, etc.

how to display all available information efficiently? I mean, less using IFs... because currently here's what I'm doing :

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>First Name : </td>
<td>John</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name : </td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>

<?php
if (!empty($hobby)){
echo '<tr>
<td>Hobby : </td>
<td>'.$hobby.'</td>
</tr>';}
?>

<?php
if (!empty($YahooID)){
echo '<tr>
<td>Yahoo ID : </td>
<td>'.$YahooID.'</td>
</tr>';}
?>

...
</table>
```

Comment: Can't you just refactor each `if(something) { ... }` into a separate function, then array_walk this function over an array of 'varname' => 'label' structure?

Comment: Wrap it in a function and/or use loops with appropriate variables to reduce code repetitiveness. The usual programing tools...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over your attributes (firstName, lastName...) or columns (DB side) and if set, add a key/value entry in some array : nameOfAttribute, valueOfAttribute.

When rendering HTML, loop through this array

```
echo '<tr><td>'.$key.' : '</td><td>'.$value+'</td></tr>';
```

Or,

```
function renderIfSet($value, $title)
{
   if ($value) return '<tr><td>$title :</td><td>$value</td></tr>';
}
```

And your code turns into:

```
<? echo renderIfSet($hobby, "Hobby") ?>
<? echo renderIfSet($YahooID, "Yahoo ID") ?>
```

Comment: putting DB result into array and loop it as $key and $value is a brilliant solution!!! I will pick your answer as best solution here...

Answer (score 4):

```
    function someAction($data) {
        if (!empty($data['data'])) {
            return '<tr>
            <td>{$data[title]} : </td>
            <td>'.$data['data'].'</td>
            </tr>';             
        }
    }

$datas = array(
  array('data' => $YahooID, 'title' => 'YahooID'),
  .... );

foreach($datas as $k => $v) {
   echo someAction($)
}
```

something like that

Answer (score 2):

Create a function...

```
function checkVal($label,$value){
    if(!empty($value)){
        $row .= '<td>'.$label.'</td>';
        $row .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
}
```

Call your function...

```
checkVal('Hobby',$hobby);
```